# golang: read text file line by line of int strings

Tags: string, file, go, int

I am dealing with an input file containing a list of integers as a string

```
10
..
```

I have choosen to read it line by line with [ReadString('\n')](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) method

The following code

```
line, error := inputReader.ReadString('\n')
lineStr := string(line)
```

console output (length and value)

```
lineStr %v 4
lineStr %v 10
```

lineStr as a length of "4", maybe because of rune encoding.

Then I have tried several way to convert it to simple integer but with no success.

**Ex1**

```
num, _ := strconv.ParseUint(lineStr, 0, 64)
```

ouputs a num of 0 (should be 10)

**Ex2**

```
num, _ := strconv.Atoi(lineStr)
```

ouputs a num of 0 (should be 10)

**Ex3**

```
num, _ := strconv.Atoi("10")
```

ouputs a num of 10 (ok)

**Ex4**

```
num, _ := strconv.ParseUint("10", 0, 64)
```

ouputs a num of 10 (ok)

string in literal are ok but string from file do not work, what is wrong ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I gonna try ScanLines instead too now

Comment: Please, check the errors in the examples (and always). They will tell you why it returned 0 (the zero-value) instead of what you are expecting.

Comment: I will but this case was so trivial to watch it carefuly but thank you for advise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation: "ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter."

Because of this, i suggest you use a scanner, which handles this case like you would expect:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
for scanner.Scan() {
    lineStr := scanner.Text()
    num, _ := strconv.Atoi(lineStr)
    fmt.Println(lineStr, num)
}
```

Comment: I was re implementing it with a scanner and it works, thank you all

Comment: Although I like using `bufio.Scanner` as well, for this specific case a simple `fmt.Fscanln(r, &intvar)` works well (perhaps wrapping the original reader with `bufio.NewReader` for more efficient reading depending on the source).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation of `ReadString` you will notice that the `string` returned will include the delimiter (in your case `\n`).

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input,
>   returning a string containing the data up to and including the
>   delimiter.

And because the length of the line after reading 10 is 4 I would assume that the lines are delimited by `\r\n`. The easiest way to remove it is using one of the `Trim` functions (like [TrimSpace](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace)).

Comment: I was escaping '\n' but not '\r' thank you, trust me I was reading the documentation about delimiter included but forgot about carriage return char

Answer (score 1):

Citing the documentation of [bufio.Reader.ReadString](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) (emphasis mine):

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data **up to and including the delimiter**.

Now, the documentation of [strconv.ParseInt](https://godoc.org/strconv#ParseInt)

> The errors that ParseInt returns have concrete type *NumError and include err.Num = s. **If s is empty or contains invalid digits, err.Err = ErrSyntax and the returned value is 0**

Your problem is that the `ReadString` method return also the `\n` that terminate the line, which is an invalid character for the `ParseInt` function.

You can check the real error with the following snippet

```
i, err := strconv.ParseInt(line, 10, 64)
if err != nil {
    switch err.(*strconv.NumError).Err {
        case strconv.ErrSyntax:
            fmt.Println("syntax error")
        case strconv.ErrRange:
            fmt.Println("out of range value")
    }
}
```

Advice: use [`strings.TrimSpace`](https://godoc.org/strings#TrimSpace) to clean your input.