# How to print out the value in a function from a user input in Go

Tags: function, go

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func Option1() {
     fmt.Println("Option1")
}
func main() {
     for true {
         fmt.Println("Pleae enter text: ")
         reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
         text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
         if text == "1" {
                Option1()
         }

      }
 }
```

So my code will eventually have multi functions example: option1 option2 and etc.. I'm trying to execute a function every time a user types 1, 2, 3 and etc, but my code doesn't print out whatever is in Option1.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: [From the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio?tab=doc#Reader.ReadString): "ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to **and including the delimiter**." (emphasis mine).

Comment: The delimiter `\n` is included in the value returned by ReadString.  In addition, the program discards data buffered from stdin.  Use a [Scanner](https://godoc.org/bufio#example-Scanner--Lines) instead.   See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983831/golang-read-text-file-line-by-line-of-int-strings) for more info.

Comment: You can also just check the value of `text[:1]`.

Comment: @larsks That will not work as you expect on all operating systems.  Use a Scanner.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Can you show me an example code I can use? I just started learning GO 2 days ago, I'm still a noob.

Comment: @MikeCash My first comment links to [an example](https://godoc.org/bufio#example-Scanner--Lines).

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thank you, that was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @CeriseLimón Sorry to bother you again, but I have one more question. How do I use fmt.Println("Enter: ") with the new code? Cause it only prints it out after the user enters something.

Comment: `for { fmt.Println(prompt); if !scanner.Scan() { break }; text := scanner.Text(); /* do something with text */}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ground rule is **ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter.** So I used `text = strings.TrimSpace(text)` to trim it before comparing .See the modified program.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func Option1() {
    fmt.Println("Option1")
}
func main() {

    for true {
        fmt.Println("Pleae enter text: ")
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Println("Length of text,before trimming:", len(text))
        text = strings.TrimSpace(text)
        fmt.Println("Length of text,after trimming:", len(text))
        if text == "1" {
            Option1()
        }

    }
}
```

Oputput is

```
VScode> go run sofstringcompare.go
Pleae enter text: 
1
Length of text,before trimming: 3
Length of text,after trimming: 1
Option1
```